# Passing v-model email value to methods

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi I'm trying to pass a v-model on an input to try and send an email reset verification but I can't figure out how to pass it from the input to the sendPasswordResetEmail correctly.
This is what I have so far

```
 methods:{
  
      resetPassword(){
          const auth = app.auth();          
          const userEmail = ref('')
          auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(userEmail.value).catch((error) =>  {
              console.log(error);
          });
          alert('Reset email has been sent')
          console.log(userEmail)
          
      },
    },
```

And this is the input part

```
<form v-if="reset" @submit.prevent="resetPassword">
<input type="email" required placeholder="email" v-model="userEmail" class="inline-block">
<button>Reset Password</button>
 
</form>
```

I've been trying to return the userEmail also but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are getting the user email value in the `resetPassword()` function. If not, then the problem is in referencing.

Correct this line,

```js
const userEmail = ref('')
```

You have to use the **this** keyword if you using the value from the HTML v-model.

Comment: That was it not using this. thankyou